# How can I find objects which are no longer being used?

Tags: java

I'm working on a big Java project which has been around for a while (i.e. before my time).  The program operates in several phases and many objects get retained from the earlier phases and are used in later phases.  I've found several groups/categories of object which get retained for no good reason but I suspect there are more.

So my question is, are there any good tools which can show me which Objects haven't been touched since a particular point in time continued not to be touched until the end of the program.  I've been using "yourkit" to examine all the objects but it's often unclear whether they need to be retained or not.  If I had something which combined the memory calculations/reporting of yourkit with some kind of coverage tool, I'd be a happy man.

Comment: What do you mean under "touched" object?

Comment: I mean an object which has had one of it's methods called or one of it's public fields accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use VisualVM to examine the heap, and to monitor garbage collection.  You should be able to set a breakpoint in your program, then take a look for things you suspect shouldn't be kept around and find out what's keeping a reference to them.

I used to use a commercial tool called (JProbe?) that did just what you want, but that was 8-9 years ago, I don't know if it's still available, or what it might be called if it is.

Comment: Hi, that sounds like a similar tool to Yourkit.  Does it provide any coverage component?

Comment: Yes, it was pretty nice.  It had a debugger-style inteface, so you could step through your code and see the current thread's stack, what was allocated at each method invocation, what was allocated on the heap as opposed to the stack frame, lots of stuff.

Answer (score 3):

A weak reference is used to determine when an object is no longer being referenced.

```
  // Create the weak reference. 
     ReferenceQueue rq = new ReferenceQueue(); 
     WeakReference wr = new WeakReference(object, rq); 
  // Wait for all the references to the object. 
  try { 
         while (true) 
        {  
              Reference r = rq.remove(); 
              if (r == wr) 
               { // Object is no longer referenced. } 
         } 
     } 
     catch (InterruptedException e) { }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of weak refs but what exactly is your idea?  I want to analyse my program in it's current state.  

I guess I could find some way to automatically add weak references to a collection for every object I create and then check that collection....  Was that what you where thinking?

Comment: If the objects were no longer referenced they would be GCed. The question implies that there are still strong references to these objects so they will never be GCed.

Comment: Actually, even this wouldn't really help me.  You see I know the objects which objects are referenced.  What I want to know is are they used... i.e. Do they need to be referenced.

Comment: this is to find objects which are not used.. so i thought this information might help you

Comment: It is a useful technique, I tend to use weak refs when I'm implementing an object cache.  I.e. Let me reuse this object if it hasn't already been GC'd...  However, I don't think it can help me in this particular scenario.